# Check Internet Connection in Background Continuously if App is Running or Not/Closed

Tags: android, kotlin, sms, internet-connection

How to Check Internet Connection in Service like that we do in Activity.
I want to Read SMS containing Specific Words and save those to my DB. Then I want to Send to Server when it's Received. but in case of No Internet What can I do ?
Thanks..

Comment: When you receive an SMS, schedule a `WorkManager` task, with a constraint that the work should be done when you have Internet access.

Comment: Means for Every SMS Received, do i have to Create WorkManager task individually ?
Actually What I need to achieve is when SMS is received, sync/send SMS to server and depending on response from Server,i have to retry sync/send SMS each time for each individual SMS.